# Somar um valor total e retornar muitas linhas

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two tables (order header and order lines). I want to add the order lines, group by month and year, but it brings me all the rows of all the orders. Have you any way to sum it up?

This is probably because I'm doing one calculation per line.
I need to do it per line because the stock is from a few different places.
For example, one stock is from the back street and another stock is from the other block.
If I use the total discount for the sales order, it doubles the same order if the inventory comes from different places.
and if I use the calculation to make the discount per line, it will bring line by line (for sure).
Was there any other possibility?
I tried with variable, but I can not pass more than one value on the same variable.

```
SELECT   
    MONTH(X.DOCDATE) MES,
    YEAR(X.DOCDATE) ANO,
    (100 - X.DiscPrcnt)* SUM(LineTotal) /100 as 'TOTAL'  
FROM RDR1 INNER JOIN ORDR X ON RDR1.DocEntry = X.DocEntry 
WHERE X.CANCELED <> 'Y'
      AND X.DocTotal > 0 
      AND X.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20190630' 
      AND OcrCode IN ('EXT', 'EXT-JD')
Group by 
    X.DOCDATE, 
    X.DiscPrcnt
ORDER BY X.DOCDATE
```

I would like it to be:

```
Month YEAR Total
1     2014  5000
2     2014  7000
```

Comment: Please translate the title and corresonding tags, like mysql

Comment: I meant add the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you want to be grouping by month and year rather than the full date. Also, I think you may not want a separate row for each discount percent value right?

How about this query?:-

```
SELECT   
    MONTH(X.DOCDATE) MES,
    YEAR(X.DOCDATE) ANO,
    SUM((100 - X.DiscPrcnt)* X.LineTotal/100)  as 'TOTAL'  
FROM RDR1 INNER JOIN ORDR X ON RDR1.DocEntry = X.DocEntry 
WHERE X.CANCELED <> 'Y'
      AND X.DocTotal > 0 
      AND X.DocDate BETWEEN '20140101' AND '20190630' 
      AND OcrCode IN ('EXT', 'EXT-JD')
Group by 
    YEAR(X.DOCDATE),
    MONTH(X.DOCDATE)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(X.DOCDATE),
    MONTH(X.DOCDATE)
```

Comment: Wow !! How could I not see it that way?
Very thanks for the help, Paul Humphreys!
Unfortunately I have to make the calculation of the discount per line, otherwise sql brings the same request dusa times with the total equal value because of an order line. For example, stock 'EXT' and 'EXT-JD' in the same order.
Once again, thank you for taking the time to help me!